# Accessing LAN Machines While Connected to Proton VPN

Tags: networking, vpn

When I am not connected to Proton VPN I can access other devices on my local network, including the NAS I use for backups. Once I connect to Proton VPN I can no longer access anything on the LAN. Proton support says its a firewall setting but GuFw shows as disabled.
I tried playing with the settings to no avail.
Any help you all can offer would be greatly appreciated.